# New Website, Digital Ocean spam traffic very high on Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, web-development, analytics, spam

I am hosting my website on a Digital Ocean droplet. It's very new and I'm not expecting any activity yet. However looking at the Analytics I started to notice a high daily increase from a particular source: *digital ocean inc.*

[image: digital ocean inc. Google Analytics]

And when filtering by "Service Provider" it becomes apparent:

[image: digital ocean inc. Service Provider]

I have attempted to add a filter, however "Service Provider" is not an option to choose. I cannot filter by IP Address, because looking at my Webserver Access Log, it changes. However it always makes these 4 same *GET* requests:

[image: Web server Access Log]

How do I get around filtering this spam traffic? What does this bot achieve by performing these simple requests?

Comment: This is not spam. Call your host to find out what this is. It is likely a monitor process that ensures your site is available.

Comment: @closetnoc It's unlikely a process monitoring service since it would not make specific GET requests to the mentioned files. I have created a support ticket with Digital Ocean. Will post update.

Comment: Yeah it would. I used to be a web host and one of my monitors, the external monitor, made standard HTTP requests just like a browser. These would fetch all resources within a page just like a user. I used to filter these in my Sawmill reports. My other monitors were against services and other things in a heads-up display that was monitored 24 hours a day by personnel in the NOC. However, like I said, I had another network purely to monitor sites including changes such as hacking, spam, etc. as well as whether a site was available via the Internet. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc you are right. See DO's response below. Sorry. Thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@closetnoc](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/36029/closetnoc) was right.

I have contacted Digital Ocean and they responded with:

> It looks like these IPs are related to a monitoring service, are you
>   currently subscribed to one? If not, it's entirely possible the person
>   who had this IP address before you was the one subscribed, and simply
>   hasn't updated their information.
>
> If it's not your monitoring, it's nothing to worry about and will
>   likely stop in the near future. If it is yours, then you know they're
>   doing their job!

I was wrong with saying "4 same GET requests", as this is obviously just a single request to the landing page and the other resources are loaded in by default.

So for now I will manually block those IP's (7 so far) in Google Analytics.

Comment: I am glad you got your answer and I very much appreciate you sharing the answer here! Cheers!!